# Hyperledger explorer [DEBUG] FabricClient - Admin peer Not found for grpc://localhost:7051

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

**Not able to configure explorer 3.8 with fabric 1.2**
I'm trying to integrate hyperledger explorer with fabric and i'm not using TLS its false in my case. can some one please help me here.

Hyperledger explorer 3.8

Hyperledger fabric 1.2

Node js v8.11.4

postgresql 9.5

**logs/console/console.log**

```
postgres://hppoc:password@127.0.0.1:5432/fabricexplorer
(node:28473) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead

Please open web browser to access ：http://localhost:8080/

pid is 28473

postgres://hppoc:password@127.0.0.1:5432/fabricexplorer

Sync process is started for the network : [net_basic] and client : [org1]
(node:28493) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Synchronizer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Error :  [ 'Failed to connect client peer, please check the configuration and peer status' ]
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Closing client processor >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

**logs/app/app.log**

```
[2018-10-26 10:20:35.233] [DEBUG] FabricClient - Channel genesis hash for channel [mychannel] >> ac4b7048da8b35c7b740babcb4dd8f911c94a15e45f442d5f6291a66f9b5ec5d
[2018-10-26 10:20:35.233] [DEBUG] FabricClient - Initialized channel >> mychannel
[2018-10-26 10:20:35.244] [DEBUG] FabricClient - Set client [cli] default orderer as  >> grpc://localhost:7050
[2018-10-26 10:20:35.245] [DEBUG] FabricClient - Admin peer Not found for grpc://localhost:7051
```

**and here is my config.json**

```
{
"network-configs": {
    "net_basic": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "clients": {
            "org1": {
                "tlsEnable": false,
                "organization": "Org1MSP",
                "channel": "mychannel",
                "credentialStore": {
                    "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/credential",
                    "cryptoStore": {
                        "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/crypto"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "channels": {
            "mychannel": {
                "peers": {
                    "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
                },
                "connection": {
                    "timeout": {
                        "peer": {
                            "endorser": "9000",
                            "eventHub": "9000",
                            "eventReg": "9000"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "organizations": {
            "Org1MSP": {
                "mspid": "Org1MSP",
                "fullpath": false,
                "adminPrivateKey": {
                    "path": "/education/Example/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore"
                },
                "signedCert": {
                    "path": "/education/Example/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
                }
            },
            "OrdererMSP": {
                "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
                "adminPrivateKey": {
                    "path": "/education/Example/basic-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore"
                }
            }
        },
        "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {
                "tlsCACerts": {
                    "path": "/education/Example/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
                },
                "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
                "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053",
                "grpcOptions": {
                    "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
                }
            }
        },
        "orderers": {
            "orderer.example.com": {
                "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
            }
        }
    },
    "network-2": {}
  },
"configtxgenToolPath": "/home/ubuntu/user/binaries/fabric-samples/bin/",
"license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the last line (CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT)

```
peer0.org1.example.com:
container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
environment:
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

in the corresponding docker-compose.yml which describes the network.
Without this line, it seems that peer is only visible inside the org.
You need also to ./generate.sh and ./start.sh your network.
Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks its work for me but again i'm getting synchronization error 
TypeError: this.client.hfc_client.getEventHub is not a function 
TypeError: this.peerEventHub.disconnect is not a function
TypeError: this.peerEventHub.disconnect is not a function

i'm getting blank page on 
http://localhost:8080 like 
Cannot GET / 
but the http://localhost:8080/api-docs this url working fine for me.

Comment: Hard to guess without more details...it seems a problem with the explorer installation, related maybe to the npm (install, test, etc) you had to do during the install. Can you check you did all of them?

Comment: yeah i did.. but my "npm run build" taking to much time, there is no response and my system got hung until and unless i wont kill build process.

Comment: Well, at least we know where the problem is. Try removing package-lock.json and the entire node_modules directory. Then redo each npm steps (install dependencies, test, etc).

Answer (score -2):

Configure connection to fabric by updating blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/config.json, see instructions provided in README, search for “## Fabric Configure Hyperledger Explorer”.